# React Compoment dont update after state change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have the Problem, that when my State changes in makeNewSmallThings, my render method does not update the component, can you help me? The code i will present is hortend to show mainly the important parts
The code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.smallElements = {}
    this.handleConsume = this.handleConsume.bind(this)
    this.makeNewSmallThings = this.makeNewSmallThings.bind(this)
    this.onSmallThingSpawn = this.onSmallThingSpawn.bind(this)
    let arrayOfSmallThings = this.getInitialiceArray()
    let arrayOfObjects = this.getSmallItems(arrayOfSmallThings)
    this.state = {smallThings: arrayOfSmallThings, objects: arrayOfObjects}
    this.makeNewSmallThings()

    console.log(arrayOfSmallThings)
}
makeNewSmallThings(){
    let arrayOfSmallThings = this.state.smallThings
    let arrayOfObjects = this.state.objects
    let newId = arrayOfSmallThings[arrayOfSmallThings.length - 1] + 1
    let newObject = this.createSmallThing(newId,newId)
    arrayOfSmallThings.push(newId)
    arrayOfObjects.push(newObject)
    this.setState({smallThings: arrayOfSmallThings, objects: arrayOfObjects})
    console.log(this.state.objects)
    setTimeout(this.makeNewSmallThings, 1000)
}
render(){
    return (
        <div className="Game">
            <Player />
            {this.state.objects}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you show the makeNewSmallThings function?

Comment: Sure sorry i pasted wrong :D

Comment: @BradEvans that helped, thank you

Comment: @AlexejFröbel, you are doing something quite dangerous. You are mutating the state directly with your current solution. This is because `let x = this.state.x` doesn't create a local copy, but assigns a direct reference. This means that if you then do `x = 123` is the same thing as doing `this.state.x = 123`!! First, create a local copy. For objects use `Object.assign({}, myVar)` and for arrays use `myArr.slice()`. Alternatively, the ES solution would be `let x = {this.state}` which also creates a copy.

Comment: are you doing anything with `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle of react ? If yes, would like to see that as well.

Comment: I guess you're using PureComponent but don't understand what it is. If you want to modify state you need to return a new value under that key, not modify an existing array or object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `setState` improperly. You're changing the state directly, then using `setState` to set the arrays inside state to values they already have.

To fix this, make a copy of the arrays before changing them, change the copies, then change the state by passing the changed copies to `setState`.

The offending lines

```
let arrayOfSmallThings = this.state.smallThings
let arrayOfObjects = this.state.objects
```

should be changed to

```
let arrayOfSmallThings = [...this.state.smallThings]
let arrayOfObjects = [...this.state.objects]
```

## Example

To run this example

1. create a react app using **create-react-app**.
2. change `App.js` and `index.js` to match the below code.
3. `npm start`

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Player extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Player</p>
        )
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.smallElements = {}
        this.handleConsume = this.handleConsume.bind(this)
        this.makeNewSmallThings = this.makeNewSmallThings.bind(this)
        this.onSmallThingSpawn = this.onSmallThingSpawn.bind(this)
        let arrayOfSmallThings = this.getInitialiceArray()
        let arrayOfObjects = this.getSmallItems(arrayOfSmallThings)
        this.state = {smallThings: arrayOfSmallThings, objects: arrayOfObjects}
        this.makeNewSmallThings()

        console.log(arrayOfSmallThings)
    }

    handleConsume() {
        console.log('handleConsume')
    }
    onSmallThingSpawn = e => {
        console.log(e)
    }
    getInitialiceArray() {
        return [0]
    }
    getSmallItems(array) {
        return array.map(item => (<span key={item}> {item} </span>))
    }

    makeNewSmallThings(){
        let arrayOfSmallThings = this.state.smallThings // Change me to [...this.state.smallThings]
        let arrayOfObjects = this.state.objects // Change me to [...this.state.objects]
        let newId = arrayOfSmallThings[arrayOfSmallThings.length - 1] + 1
        let newObject = this.createSmallThing(newId,newId)
        arrayOfSmallThings.push(newId)
        arrayOfObjects.push(newObject)
        this.setState({smallThings: arrayOfSmallThings, objects: arrayOfObjects})
        console.log(this.state.objects)
        setTimeout(this.makeNewSmallThings, 1000)
    }

    createSmallThing(id, id2) {
        return (
            <span key={id}> {id2} </span>
        )
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="Game">
                <Player />
                {this.state.objects}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Change the lines with comments in `App.js` and see the app go from non-functioning to functioning.